# How to write integration tests in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

There are three basic layers of testing:

1. Unit test — making sure each function/unit of code works as expected
2. Functional test — making sure units interact with each other as expected
3. Integration test — making sure our app integrate with other app/api/services as expected

I can handle cases 1. and 2. using Xcode's `iOS Unit Testing Bundle` and `iOS UI Testing Bundle` I don't know how to write tests from point 3.

I would like to write to tests to check if me app correctly integrate with backend, BLE device, etc.

Note that I have already written unit tests which I run using CI.

Integration test should not be run in CI because it depends on external environment. I would like to run its only manually.

How to handle it in Xcode? Second `Unit Testing Target`? Any advice? How are you dealing with it in yours systems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the style of integration test that you are after you may want to use dedicated a unit or UI tests target.

From your question I'm guessing the style you want to have leans towards black box testing with other real systems. If that's the case a **dedicated UI tests target** would do the job.

With UI tests you can do stuff like opening other apps on the device and test how your app interacts with them. For example, [this post](https://blog.branch.io/ui-testing-universal-links-in-xcode-9/) shows how to write a UI test that uses the Messages app to test Universal Links.

[image: animation showing an integration level UI test from the linked post]

I'd reach for using a dedicated unit tests target only if you need to control part of the code in your app, for example stubbing network requests. But that doesn't really fit with the definition of integration test you have given.